# Parametrize return type based on concrete type of typeclass

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, polymorphism, typeclass, first-order-logic

Consider I have the following template for two typeclasses:

```
data TheoryParseErr = TheoryParseErr deriving (Show)

class Theory t where
    applySemantics
        :: (Functor f, TheorySymbol s)
        => t
        -> f a
        -> f (Either TheoryParseErr s)

class TheorySymbol a where
  readT  :: String -> Either TheoryParseErr a
```

I want to have multiple instances of these typeclasses. For instance, the Uninterpreted Functions:

```
data UfTheory = UfTheory deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Theory UfTheory where
  applySemantics _ = fmap readT

data UfSymbol = Uninterpreted String deriving (Show)

instance TheorySymbol UfSymbol where
    readT s = Right $ Uninterpreted s
```

However, this is not possible, because the function

```
applySemantics:: (Foldable f, TheorySymbol s) => t -> f a -> f (Either TheoryParseErr s)
```

is giving types of `forall a. a` and `forall TheorySymbol s. s`.

Ideally, I want to control which types `a` and `s` are for my choice of type `t`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hint: MultiParamTypeClasses and TypeFamilies

Comment: @Li-yaoXia No, MultiParamTypeClasses won't work because I *don't* want flexibility between the Theory (e.g. `UfTheory`) and its symbols (e.g. `Ufsymbols`) -- they should be bound to each other.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Functor` constraint? You can float the constraint to the end of the method `applySemantics :: TheorySymbol s => t -> (forall f. Functor f => f a -> f (Either TheoryParseErr s))` and `(forall f. Functor f => f a -> f b)` is isomorphic to `a -> b` ([*4.1 Double Yoneda*](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/proyo.pdf)). So the class is equivalent to `class Theory t where applySemantics :: TheorySymbol s => t -> a -> Either TheoryParseErr s`.

Comment: Re: "they should be bound to each other" Sounds like functional dependencies.